# git, remote access - ssh

Tags: git, ssh, cygwin

I have two computers with windows xp.

I want to use the first one as git server and second one as working station.

On local computer works git very well, but for comunication between 2 computers I need ssh. (I suppose)

I've found program sshwindows, but I cant install him, some error during instalation.
Another posibility is cygwin, but I have no experience with that.

Is there any other Idea, how can I make git server and client for 2 computers on XP?

Answer (score 2):

Don't bother with cygwin. MSysGit bash is very nice.

The simplest solution is to use the file url.

I would advise against using the `\\server\share\repo` specification as submodules do not work using this syntax.

Use the `file:///\\server\share\repo` syntax so when you decide to use a submodule eventually, you will not have to rewrite your urls.

Should you need to have a secure connection and some administration, I would highly recommend going the linux route by installing a small vm via virtualbox and an ubuntu server install. Gitolite, gitweb, etc should be nice and easy to do lots there if you want to integrate with a tracker, etc.

Many painful years of using Git as an early adopter and still using it on windows has shown that this is the least painful way of going about it.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

ssh is not the only option.

> Git natively supports ssh, git, http,
>   https, ftp, ftps, and rsync protocols.
>   The following syntaxes may be used
>   with them:
>
> - ssh://[user@]host.xz[:port]/path/to/repo.git/
> - git://host.xz[:port]/path/to/repo.git/
> - http[s]://host.xz[:port]/path/to/repo.git/
> - ftp[s]://host.xz[:port]/path/to/repo.git/
> - rsync://host.xz/path/to/repo.git/
>
> For local repositories, also supported
>   by git natively, the following
>   syntaxes may be used:
>
> - /path/to/repo.git/
> - file:///path/to/repo.git/

So for example you can make a shared directory and use that as remote repository.

Comment: To get any significant number of those protocols going on this setup is not worth the headache. Also, in windows, file:/// and \\ can be used for "remote" repositories in a windows environment. The other issue with the local reference by ../relative/path/to/repo.git/ falls apart for submodules. With submodules you don't want absolute paths anyway due to portability of the structure.

Answer (score 0):

Set up a windows shared directory (called something like `gitroot`) on your server and put your repositories in there. You will then be able to clone on your working machine using something like:

```
git clone file:///\\server\gitroot\repo.git
```

Comment: This reference starts to fall apart under windows. file:///\\server is preferred.

Comment: Edited. Thanks for the tip @adymitruk. I have to admit, I didn't test it thoroughly, but it did seem to work for the clone.